# How to assign a slice to a slice in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Having:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df_one = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,3), columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
```

And:

```
df_two = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([2,3]), columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
```

When I try to assign, like this:

```
df_one.loc[2:4, 'colB'] = df_two.loc[:, 'colB']
```

I get:

```
colA    colB    colC
0.37    0.95    0.73
0.59    0.15    0.15
0.05    NaN     0.60
0.70    NaN     0.96
```

When expecting to get:

```
colA    colB    colC
0.37    0.95    0.73
0.59    0.15    0.15
0.05    1.0     0.60
0.70    1.0     0.96
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Using `to_list` might give you incorrect results

Comment: Ok, I am doing it right now

Comment: OK so you deliberately want to remove index alignment, then this is fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done adding a to_list() at the end:

```
df_one.loc[2:4, 'colB'] = df_two.loc[:, 'colB'].to_list()
```

Or:

```
df_one.loc[2:4, 'colB'] = df_two.loc[:, 'colB'].values
```

Comment: `.values` is probably more efficient~